# First time use of Tomcat and the Stripes framework

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp, stripes

I recently decided to try some java web development, so I installed xampp, the tomcat add-on, and java. I have looked at some of the JSP page examples that came with it, so I know that tomcat is at least working. **However when I threw the stripes folder into the same examples directory and tried to access the files I received the following error.**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The
>   absolute uri:
>   http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this
>   application

**Now, I am a complete beginner when it comes to using tomcat or jsp pages in general.** I may have missed some trivially easy step. I have searched the web for a few hours and I haven't found a very good tutorial on how to set up and start using the stripes framework. **So let me know if you have any input or links to help me resolve this issue and get started coding.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Quick Start Guide](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide) for Stripes. There is also a [sample app](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Sample+Application) included as part of Stripes download.

Note that you have to deploy that sample app as web application in Tomcat (e.g. copy `war` file to Tomcat's `webapps` folder), you can't just "throw stripes folder" into 'examples'.

Comment: Ok that's my problem. I deployed the .war file that came with Stripes as you recommended and it worked great. What is the reason for having to deploy projects. I know in asp.net pages are compiled on the file does tomcat operate differently?

Comment: **Individual** JSP files can be compiled in place, e.g. if you change `jsp/dates/date.jsp` from your Tomcat examples folder, you'll see the change reflected in your browser instantly. Entire application has to be deployed because it includes things other than pages - web.xml descriptor at a minimum. Take a look at Java EE Tutorial for a more detailed explanation: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue is a missing jar file. As of Stripes 1.5.3 the error is a bit different:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I copied jstl.jar and standard.jar from the examples lib to my app's lib, and the app launched fine afterwards.